Need help for tube like surface in geo-nodes
I would like to do something similar to the picture posted here.
Geo-nodes would be great, so I can apply it on different geometry.
If it is less organic and more straight, it would be even better.
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!




Could you describe what "underlying" surface/set of curves you have to support this circumvolution of tubes ? It is related to the sentence: "I can apply it on different geometry"...

Hello Stef,
I just updated the main question with a picture that describe what I meant.
Please let me know if you have other questions.
Thank you! :)

That doesn't make this any clearer to me.

I would maybe look into something along these lines.

Thank you @jakemoyo, I think this is a good solution.

@TheJeran, please let me know what you don't understand.

I wanted to look for the exact video Jakemoyo posted. Though it's not clear what you mean by "more straight" - maybe you could create a path through all edges and convert it to a Hilbert Curve

Hello Markus,
I added a new picture in the main message to explain "More straight".
The goal is to have pipes on this surface. In order to create a sci-fi surface.
Let me know if it clarifies things!
Thanks again!
